# Perturbative Kolmogorov Complexity Bounds

Tags: complexity-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

Are there any known bounds on the impact of changing (for example) one bit in a string on the resulting string's Kolmogorov Complexity? In mathematical terms, does the equation $|K(x) - K(x')|$ (with $K(x)$ as the Kolmogorov Complexity of $x$ and $x'$ as the string resulting from changing an arbitrary bit of $x$) have a non-trivial lower bound?

Comment: There's no reason to expect any lower bound, but there is an upper bound of $O(1)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, not $\lg n$ where $n$ is the length of $x$?

Comment: Oops... you're right.